# Stick stickies to desktop only

Tags: stickies

Is there a way to stick the stickies on Desktop, which doesn't go away when you do "Show Desktop". I don't want them to be above any applications, just over Desktop. I suppose this behaviour is similar to Sticky Notes on Windows.
If its not possible, I would like suggestions for other apps which can do so.

Comment: [Übersicht](https://tracesof.net/uebersicht/) is perhaps the closest you can find. It's like an overlay on top of the wallpaper and it has [a sticky note widget](https://tracesof.net/uebersicht-widgets/#sticky-notes-ubersicht), but I believe it doesn't work? and [hasn't been updated in a while](https://github.com/zanderp/sticky-notes-ubersicht). It'd be fairly easy to just build the widget from scratch with JS. — If you're willing to let go of that desktop idea, there are other great sticky note apps: [SideNotes](https://www.apptorium.com/sidenotes), [Ghostnote](https://www.ghostnoteapp.com/)